# Using UserControls and Sockets in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, user-controls

I'm quite new to Sockets and would appreciate if someone could give an advice.
In my Windows Forms application several users can add user controls to the same form and manage them. I am not sure if I've taken the right approach.
My first two functions are `drawing` and adding a `UserControl`. For drawing I simply send the  coordinates of `Mouse_Move` event to all clients:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (canDraw)
        {
            string coords= e.X.ToString() + "|" + e.Y.ToString();
            Sender(coords);
        }
    }

 void Sender(string msg)
 {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
        client.Send(bytes);
 }
```

When I receive the bytes, I draw them:

```
 client.Receive(bytes);

 string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
 //the received data in format "X|Y"
 string[] split_data = data.Split(new Char[] { '|' });
 Draw(Convert.ToInt32(split_data[0]),
     Convert.ToInt32(split_data[1]));
```

Draw method:

```
void Draw(int x, int y)
{
        Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics();
        graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), x, y, 5, 5);
}
```

Everything works fine at this point. Now I try to add `UserControl` to the form and send it to all clients. I simply send some sign when the control needs to be added, and create new `userControl`:

```
 private void AddRectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {            
    Sender("RectControl|");            
 }
```

And when I receive:

```
 client.Receive(bytes);
 if (bytes.Length != 0)
 {
   string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
   string[] split_data = data.Split(new Char[] { '|' });

   if (split_data[0] == "RectControl")
   {
       this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
       {
          RectControl control = new RectControl();
          this.Controls.Add(control);
       }));
   }
  else 
  {
     Draw(Convert.ToInt32(split_data[0]),
     Convert.ToInt32(split_data[1]));
  }
```

I am not sure if i'm doing right, maybe there is another way of implementing this?
Also, when one client performs some changes on userControl (such as move, manipulation of control content, etc.) I will have to keep track of every change and send it to all the clients. How can I know exactly which control has been changed to apply these changes for the rest ones?

Comment: Structure the msg argument passed to the Sender(string msg) method, then parse it on the receive side. You could send something like 'Add|RectControl|ControlName|X|Y' or 'Move||ControlName|X|Y' or 'Remove||ControlName||' as long as you have the code for sending and receiving, the message format is pretty much up to you. Keep in mind that if multiple users are all running your app on multiple computers then watchout for control name collisions, or other gotchas like user A deleting control X while user B is moving control X.

Comment: Thank you, I thought there could be other tools that allow sending the whole object, seems not :)

Answer (score 1):

PLED gives good advice. I would add:

It is unclear what transport protocol you are using. If UDP, you might drop packets, so some clients might see new controls or moved controls that other clients do not.

I am guessing you use TCP for guaranteed delivery and congestion control. Keep in mind TCP is a streaming protocol. That means when you send a 50-byte message, you might receive that message all at once in one Receive call, or as many as 50 different Receive calls 1 byte at a time.

Also, you might receive multiple messages in a single Receive call.

Look up "TCP Framing". On each Receive, make sure you read in all full messages, hold onto any extra bytes that are part of the next message, and then make your next Receive call. One way to simplify framing is to use a length-prefix of 4 bytes before each message, so that you know when you are done reading a full message.

I would also recommend looking up protobuf-net (or another implementation of google protocol buffers), which will handle the serialization for you, and allow you to deal with simple types, where each field of your message is a property of the type. That would avoid the need to parse up the string. protobuf-net is extensible, so if you decide to add new fields to the message later, it's easier and won't break existing deployed builds.